# Python, Unittest, sys.argv used to define global var in script. How to correctly test?

Tags: python, unit-testing

I want to test a script that looks like this:
**my_script.py**

```
import argparse, sys

def my_parser(args=sys.argv[1:]):
  parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="my parser")
  parser.add_argument("--my-arg", dest="my_arg", required=True)
  args, _ = parser.parse_known_args(args=args)
  return args

args = my_parser()

def do_something():
  res = 5+1
  return res

def main():
  use_args = args
  res = do_something()
  # whatevere here
```

When I try to run a unittest for the function `do_something()` I always get the error of the parser requiring input arguments. My test is something like:
**my_test.py**

```
from unittest import TestCase
from my_script import sys, do_something

class MyTest(TestCase):
  def test_do_something(self):
    test_sys_argv = ["dummy", "--my-arg", "dummy_arg"]
    with patch.object(sys, "argv", test_sys_argv):
      out = do_something()
    self.assertEqual(out, 6)
```

The way I am doing the patch is not working. I understand that in this way I patch any reference to `sys.argv` within the function `do_something()` while, when the test is called, `sys.argv` is empty for the script.
Is it possible to solve this problem without refactoring the variable `args` within a function? I would like to have the `args` variable of **my_script.py** as a global variable of the script.
Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to test `my_parser`, just pass it an input manually in your test.  if you want to test `do_something` you don't need `sys.argv` at all, since the fn never uses args.

The problem here is just that the line

```
args = my_parser()
```

Is run whenever the script is imported, i.e. before the test.*  Move it inside main, or inside an `if __name__ == "__main__"` block.  Nothing stops args being a global var if you really want that:

```py
args = None

if __name__ == "__main__":
    args = my_parser()
```

I strongly suspect you will only ever evaluate the args exactly once---at runtime, in which case I'm not quite sure why you don't just use `argparse` the usual way without sys.argv.

Your attempt to patch sys.argv doesn't work, because it occurs after the import, and the function has already got an empty sys.argv when it was first defined.  (Muteable default args are bound when the function is defined, although in this case it doesn't even matter, as the function is *called* before you get to the test.)  You might want consider defining it like this:

```py
def my_parser(args = None):
    args = args or sys.argv[1:]
    ...
```

Since sys.argv is now called inside the function, it will be evaluated at runtime, and you can patch it if you need to.  Apart from testing I can't see any reason to do this, as you don't normally modify sys.argv when running.

*You could work around this by importing inside the test function... but the whole point is that at present your 'global variable' in the module is *not* import safe.  I'm not quite sure what the execution flow is here.

P.S. If you are trying to test a command line app, you might want to look at one of the testing frameworks for simulating calling with different arguments.

Comment: Thank you! Do you think that using the `argparse` the usual way would solve the issue during tests?

Comment: @Flexo using argparse the usual way, i.e. just calling the parser without suppplying sys.argv yourself will simply make your code more normal = easier for others to read.  The problem with the tests at the moment is just that you try to parse on *import*, which of course fails.

Comment: I see, thanks a lot